# Travelling to Abu Dhabi with a passport close to the expiration date

Tags: passports, abu-dhabi, italian-citizens

We are thinking of traveling to Abu Dhabi next month but I just realized my Italian passport will expire in three months. Is this a problem?  I know in many countries you cannot go in with a passport close to expiration date. thanks

Answer (score 1):

[According to Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=IT&DE=AUH&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines for immigration information:

> Passport required.
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date.
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to
>     passengers who stay less than 3 months must be valid for a
>     minimum of 3 months from the arrival date. This does not
>     apply when entering in Abu Dhabi (AUH).

The same six month requirement is stated on [UAE government websites](https://www.uae-embassy.org/services-resources/visas-passports/non-us-citizens).

Accordingly, you'd need to renew your passport before you travel.